# Options to lessen database open connection?

Tags: php, perl, database-connection

I have a free application that is very used and I get around 500 to 1000 concurrent users from time to time.

This application is a desktop application that will communicate with my website API to receive data every 5 ~ 15 minutes as well as send back minimum data about 3 selects top every 15 minutes.

Since users can turn the application on and off as they wish the timer for each one of them to query my API may vary and as such I have been hitting the max connection limit available for my hosting plan.

Not wanting to upgrade it for financial matter as well as because it is a non-profitable application for the moment **I am searching for other options to reduce the amount of connections and cache some information that can be cached.**

The first thing that came to my mind was to use FastCGI with Perl I have tested it for some time now and it seems to work great but I have to problems while using it:

1. if for whatever reason the application goes idle for 60 the
   server kills it and for the next few requests it will reply with
   error 500 until the script is respawned which takes about 3+ minutes
   (yes it takes that much I have tried my code locally on my own test
   server and it comes up instantly so I am sure it is a server issue
   of my hosting company but they don't seem like wanting to resolve
   it).
2. the kill timeout which is set to 300 and will kill/restart the
   script after that period which would result on the above said at 1)
   about the respawn of the script.

Given that I am now looking for alternatives that are not based on FastCGI if there is any.
Also due to the limitations of the shared host I can't make my own daemon and my access to compile anything is very limited.

**Are there any good options that I can archive this with either Perl or PHP ?**

Mainly reduce the database open connections to a minimum and still be able to cache some select queries for returning data... The main process of the application is inserting/updating data anyway so there inst much to cache.

This was the simple code I was using for testing it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use CGI::Simple; # Can't use CGI as it doesn't clear the data for the 
                 # next request haven't investigate it further but needed 
                 # something working to test and using CGI::Simples was 
                 # the fastest solution found.
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;

use lib qw( /home/my_user/perl_modules/lib/perl/5.10.1 );
use FCGI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:mydatabase:mymysqlservername',
                       'username', 'password', 
                       {RaiseError=>1,AutoCommit=>1}
                      ) || die &dbError($DBI::errstr);

my $request = FCGI::Request();
while($request->Accept() >= 0)
{
    my $query   = new CGI::Simple;
    my $action  = $query->param("action");
    my $id      = $query->param("id");
    my $server  = $query->param("server");
    my $ip      = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};

    print $query->header();

    if ($action eq "exp")
    {
        my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{
                            INSERT INTO 
                               my_data (id, server) VALUES (?,INET_ATON(?))
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                               server = INET_ATON(?)});
        my $result = $sth->execute($id, $server, $server)
                             || die print($dbh->errstr);
        $sth->finish;
        if ($result)
        {
            print "1";
        }
        else
        {
            print "0";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "0";
    }
}

$dbh->disconnect || die print($DBI::errstr);
exit(0);

sub dbError
{
    my ($txt_erro) = @_;
    my $query = new CGI::Simple;
    print $query->header();
    print "$txt_erro";
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, you probably want to look at CGI::Fast instead of CGI::Simple to resolve your CGI.pm not dealing in the expected manner with persistent variables...

Answer (score 1):

Run a proxy.  Perl's DBD::Proxy should fit the bill.  The proxy server shouldn't be under your host's control, so its 60-???-of-inactivity rule shouldn't apply here.

Alternatively, install a cron job that runs more often than the FastCGI timeout, simply to wget some "make activity" page on your site, and discard the output.  Some CRMs do this to force a "check for updates" for example, so it's not completely unusual, though somewhat of an annoyance here.

Comment: I am a bit confused here as to `The proxy server shouldn't be under your host's control` could you perhaps give me a bigger insight of how it work and how it would not be under my host's control ? `60-???-of-inactivity` 60 seconds sorry ;) `install a cron job that runs more often than the FastCGI timeout` I was thinking of using the Google schedule task to hit it every once in a while not sure if that would workout well.

Comment: @Prix - Host's control: yes, it's running on their server, but it's not started by their web server (apache?), so it's unlikely to have anything coming along and killing it nor to have a timeout built in. Using google would work, I just think a local cron job is nicer :-)

Comment: I see I will have to check that with them to see if they even have it running but seems interesting... Will let u know of their reply once I hear back from them.

Comment: Unhappily that is not an available option in there too ;(